# Php Memcached's PAYLOAD_FAILURE error and how to set value in perl compatible to php-memcached

Tags: php, perl, caching, memcached, php-7

I am trying to **GET** the earlier stored data using PHP's MemcacheD extension but receives Memcached::RES_PAYLOAD_FAILURE saying unable to serialize the data. As per the [official php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.constants.php), it appears to be compression or serialization issue.

> **Memcached::RES_PAYLOAD_FAILURE**
>
> Payload failure: could not compress/decompress or serialize/unserialize the value.

But the given data is a Json value and via Telnet I can get the JSON data

The data is set using a Perl batch  with [Cache::Memcached::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cache::Memcached::Fast) , earlier with php memcache it could read but now with php memcached it cannot.

Regarding the error, as mentioned: [on php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php#115667) the 2 extensions memcache and memcacheD appears to incompatible when mixing, but I am not sure is the real problem.

> You can't safely switch between memcache and memcached without a either a cache flush or isolated cache environments.

So my question is

1. Is it really the incompatibility issue between PHP's Memcache and Memcached causing this error?
2. If so, for fixing it I am willing to set data from perl but how can I set the data compatible with PHP memcache**d**

Note: Since with PHP7, I cannot use Memcache, I want to do with Memcached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php-memcache and php-memcache**D** are not compatible so this is not possible.